# Accessing to attributes of a templated vector while it is an element of another vector in c++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, encapsulation

I have a custom `vector` class which have the following functions, `push`, `pop`, `print` in which the `print` function will print out all elements in the vector. The private attributes of the vector are `m_current`(Current iterator), `m_size`(size of vector) and `Datatype m_data`(templated).

Now I have another class called Data which have the following attributes, `m_date`, `m_time`.

I declared 2 vectors with this.

```
vector<Data> vect1(10);
vector<Data> vect2(10);
```

And then, I declare another vector to house these vectors.

```
vector<vector<Data>> vect3(10);
vect3.push(vect1);
vect3.push(vect2);
```

My question is, just how do i access the `m_time` of `vect1` through `vect3`?

Comment: Does your custom `vector` class define any way to access its contents?

Comment: It does but I had just include what I think is needed to get the question across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your vector class implements `operator[]`, which it should, it's as simple as this:

```
vect3[0][0].m_time
```

If the element accessor has an other name, such as `get_element(int id)`, it would be

```
vect3.get_element(0).get_element(0).m_time
```

If there is no element accessor function, then congratulations, you have created [Write-only memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_%28joke%29).

Comment: Assuming `operator[]` is implemented for this custom vector class.

Comment: @FredLarson: Indeed. It seems like I simply assumed that. Wrongly, as it seems now.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working already(sort of) and yeah, I did have element accessor function, I just didn't include them here.